# When $E[f(\alpha,X)] = f(\alpha, E[X])$

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus

When $E[f(\alpha,X)] = f(\alpha,E[X])$, where $f$ is some convex function of the first and second variables, except when the first variable takes the value $\alpha$ in which case the equality holds, then intuitively f is a (locally) linear function of the second variable. But how do you prove this, i.e. prove that $f''(\alpha, E[X]) = 0$ where the prime denotes differentiation to the second variable? It's maybe simple to prove but I can't figure it out.

Comment: Do you mean for any random variable $X$ or just a particular one.

Comment: @Gordon thanks, $X$ is a particular random variable, but its distribution is not specified. $f$ is a bounded function and convex in both variables, $f$ is in fact the price of a claim.

Comment: For a particular random variable $X$ and a particular convex function, this is likely possible without $f$ being linear.

Comment: I tried expressing $E[f(\alpha, X)]$ using Carr-Madan, i.e. expressing it in terms of calls and puts on $X$ and then equating that expression to $f(\alpha, E[X])$, but that did not get me any further (unless I overlooked something).

Comment: You could assume continuity of the second derivative and take cases, i) f's second derivative is everywhere positive -> show that $E[f(\alpha, X)]$ can't be equal to the function of the expectation ii) show the same where f's second derivative is everywhere negative and iii) this means that it is somewhere positive. The result holds even when assuming a continuous first derivative, but I believe the derivation is more nuanced.

Comment: I think you can ignore the first variable, and then show that $f''(x)=0$ everywhere.

Comment: Your question is ill-posed. I suppose you meant for $\alpha$ to be deterministic rather than a random variable. But you have not specified it. However, it is so, it is irrelevant whether $f$ is convex in the first variable.

Comment: This is answered here:https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1160128/249524. You need to be careful about 1) the range of $X$ and 2) sets of measure zero. This is why the answer has the caveat about the essential range.

Comment: -1. In addition to what I have pointed out regarding the ill-posed-ness of your problem, it is ill-posed in that, you do not specify the domain of $f$.

Comment: I am on the road right now so cannot easily edit the qurstion, will do that in a few days. thanks for all the inputs so far folks.

Answer (score -1):

By [Jenson's Inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jensen%27s_inequality), $E[f(X)] >= f(E[X])$ if $f''(X) >= 0$.

When two additional constraints apply:

1) $X$ is not a constant

2) $f''(X)>0$

then

$E[f(X)] > f(E[X])$.

By contradiction, if $E[f(X)] = f(E[X])$, then either $X$ is a constant or  $f''(X) = 0$.

Edit: @Hans is correct.  I had assumed f''(x) is a constant, but that was not stated in your question.  You claim is not true.  You could have a discreet random variable X and and some arbitrary f(x) like the below.  $E[f(X)] = 0 = f(E[X])$  but the derivatives of $f$ are undefined. Although you have told us the shape of $f$ for other values of $\alpha$ we know nothing about the shape for the $\alpha$ value of interest.

[image: arbitrary pmf]

Comment: -1. This "proof" is ambiguous and wrong. $f"(X)>0$ means $f"(X)>0, \forall X$ values with at least two distinct values. First you have not proved the strict inequality $E[f(X)] > f(E[X])$ under these conditions. Second, the contradiction can only lead to the existence of some $X_0$ such that $f"(X_0)=0$ but not for all $X$.

Comment: @Hans, thank you - I have corrected it in an edit.

Comment: Your $f(\alpha=1,\cdot)$ does not seem to be convex. The problem is ill-posed as I have pointed out in the comment right below the question.  Yes, if $f$ is defined on a discrete domain, $f''$ is undefined. However, if we let $f$ be defined on an interval containing the range of $X$ and if $X$ has strictly positive measure on no less than $2$ values, $f''$ exists at $\mathbf E[X]$ and $f''(\mathbf E[X])=0$. Try to prove this.